# PHP : How to skip last element in foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have an array of objects, any array in php.
How do i skip the last element in the foreach iteration?

Comment: `if $element == end($myarray) break`

Comment: use array_pop() before foreach

Comment: @sashkello That will give undesired results if there are duplicate elements in the array, or when there are elements that evaluate to the same value as the last one.

Comment: Well, why is there an extra element at the end of your array in the first place?

Comment: @fireeyedboy Ah, true, you can otherwise use `end` on `array_keys`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use a variable to track how many elements have been iterated so far and cut the loop when it reaches the end:

```
$count = count($array);

foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    if (--$count <= 0) {
        break;
    }

    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
```

If you don't care about memory, you can iterate over a shortened copy of the array:

```
foreach (array_slice($array, 0, count($array) - 1) as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
```

Comment: i don't know why it felt like it was a bad question, but this was certainly what i was asking about. I want to loop through everything but exclude the last element in the array.. Thanks

Comment: @muffin The question is really why that last element should be excluded in the first place ... if there's something special about that value, perhaps it shouldn't be there.

Comment: Both approaches worked fine, no errors... very self explanatory. Thank You.

Comment: `array_slice( $array, 0, -1 );`

Answer (score 5):

There's various ways to do this.

If your array is a sequentially zero-indexed array, you could do:

```
for( $i = 0, $ilen = count( $array ) - 1; $i < $ilen; $i++ )
{
    $value = $array[ $i ];

    /* do something with $value */
}
```

If your array is an associative array, or otherwise not sequentially zero-indexed, you could do:

```
$i = 0;
$ilen = count( $array );
foreach( $array as $key => $value )
{
    if( ++$i == $ilen ) break;

    /* do something with $value */
}
```

Comment: This is also a good answer ..upvote thanks :)

Comment: @muffin You're welcome. As you can see from other answers, there are lots of ways to achieve what you were after.

Comment: You have a typo in for-loop. Should be a semicolon instead of a comma.

Comment: @erfan It's not a typo. I'm initializing two variables (separated by a comma) in the first part of the for loop. Each expression in `for( expr1; expr2; expr3 )` can [be empty or contain multiple expressions separated by commas](https://www.php.net/manual/control-structures.for.php).

Comment: @DecentDabbler Oh wow ... I feel dumb now XD

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to delete the last array entry with pop, you could skip it like this

```
$array = array('v1','v2','v3',...)

$counter = 1;

foreach($array as $value)
{
    //do your thing in loop

    if($counter == count($array)) continue; // this will skip to next iteration if last element encountered.
    $counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do will defeat the purpose of foreach loop. It is meant to loop through the entire array and make our job easy.

for ex: You can get the array size using **COUNT** function in php and then can use for loop and set the limit to arraysize-2, so the last array will be omitted

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = count($array);
$i=0;
foreach ($arr as &$value) 
{
    $i++;
    if($i==($count-1))
    {
      echo 'skip';
    }
    else
    {
      echo $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work if keys are strings.

Comment: @jack okk than I am editing my answer.. :)

Comment: simply do this: for($i=0;$i<$count-1;$i++)