# Make a list form php string

Tags: php, arrays, string, email, processwire

I have this code that write inside the variable `$products` a string of products name:

```
$products = '';
foreach($order->pad_products as $product) $products .= " $product->title";
```

When I print `$products` inside a HTML email body and send the email with PHP, in this case, I sand `$msg`, I see the name of the products all in one line.

```
$msg = "
  <html>
    <head>
      <style type='text/css'></style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Sent!</h1>
      <p>$name thank you</p>
        $products
    </body>
  </html>";
```

How can I make a list of these products?
and, can I delete one of these?

Comment: As you use `html` markup - add `<br />` or create a `<ul>` for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How create responsive email that send from php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51944973/how-create-responsive-email-that-send-from-php)

Comment: @RonnieOosting no, it's about how write php variable. I not about how send email.

Comment: @u_mulder thank you for your help, but in this particular situation I can't write in `html` I have to use the variable in `php`. good solution it's the one below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display them as a list, you simply have to create a list using HTML:

```
<?php
echo "<ul>";
foreach($order->pad_products as $product) {
    echo "<li>" . $product->title . "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

**Alternative, applying to your current code**

```
<?php
$products = "";
foreach($order->pad_products as $product) {
    $products .= "<li>".$product->title."</li>";
}
$msg = "
<html>
<body>
  <h1>Sent!</h1>
    $products
</body>
</html>";
```

Comment: wee, thank you! this work! was easy I didn't try this possibility! thank you!! Do you know How I can delete the last list row?

Comment: @MarcoRomano take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899944/php-how-to-skip-last-element-in-foreach-loop

Answer (score 1):

ProcessWire (which you tagged this with) lets you do this with `pop()`:

```
<?php
echo "<ul>";
$products = $order->pad_products;
$products->pop(); 
foreach($products as $product) {
    echo "<li>" . $product->title . "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Another option is to count the number of items and limit to one less than that. You should be able to use `->count()` but I don't know what pad_products is, so if that doesn't work, you could just do `count($order->pad_products)`

```
<?php
echo "<ul>";
$limit = $order->pad_products->count() - 1;
foreach($order->pad_products("limit=$limit") as $product) {
    echo "<li>" . $product->title . "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Comment: No problem - I added another option for you as well. There are many different ways to achieve this :)

Comment: nice, I will try to use. At moment for delete the Shipping Cost row I have use this:
 
`$products = '';
foreach($order->pad_products as $product) $products .= "<li>".$product->title."</li>";
$words = explode( " ", $products );
array_splice( $words, -2 );
$prod = implode( " ", $words );
echo $prod;`